# SharePointOnline: How to authenticate user from Azure AD via CSOM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

I have the following requirements:

- Create a MVC site with Azure AD authentication.
- Fetch lists from SharePointOnline/O365 which also uses the same Azure AD.
- Fetch lists from SharePointOnline/O365 anonymously (is it even possible?)

Thanks to VS2015 the first step is trivial.

But how to authenticate the current user in SharePoint? User.Identity does not provide password, so I cannot use ClientContext.Credentials.

I heard there is some Token Provider but haven't found a working case yet. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? If not, is it suitable to use the Microsoft Graph in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of SharePoint online from our MVC sites, you can consider using the Microsoft Graph REST API instead of CSOM.

You can refer [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/list) about the **list operation** of Microsoft Graph. However, since this API is in beta version, it is not recommend to use in the product version.

And you also can refer the link below to get started developing with Microsoft Graph:

[App authentication with Microsoft Graph](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/auth_overview)